# python/regex copy paragraphs in order to another txt document

Tags: python, regex, string, text

I'm working on what I initially thought would be a pretty simple program. Essentially, it should find key words then copy that paragraph to another document. What I want to do is take content from document 1 (both are .txt files) and re-order the paragraphs into a desired order.

I think I've written my python part correctly, as it works with other snippets (or seems to just fine), but the regex part (admittedly I'm very new to this) for some reason does not work.
I've tried a number of things and searched all through stack overflow. What I have currently "catches" almost the entire txt file instead of just the paragraph. This may be obvious but in addition to it catching most of the document, it's catching paragraphs without the target term (in this case, discussing) in it.

I appreciate all help in advance.

````
def write_function():
    with open('minnar.txt','r') as rf, open('regexoutput.txt', 'a') as wf:
        content = rf.read()
        matches = target.findall(content)
        print(matches)
        for match in matches:
            wf.write(match + '\n \n')

target = re.compile('([^\']*(?=discussing)[^\']*)')
write_function()```
````

Comment: What exactly means "paragraph" here? How are paragraphs separated from each other (just a newline character, an empty line,...)?

Answer (score 0):

If your *paragraph* means the text between quote, then the regex should be follow:

```
\'([^']+)\'
```

https://pythex.org/?regex=%5C%27(%5B%5E%27%5D%2B)%5C%27&test_string=This%20is%20%27the%20thing%27%20that%20I%20talked%20about.%20And%20I%20think%20this%20%27should%20be%20the%20one%20that%20they%20expected%27&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=1&verbose=0

Comment: But it's only supposed to match a paragraph if it contains the word `discussing`

Comment: My apologies. When I say copy a paragraph, I mean all the text between two blank lines., and yes, as @barmar stated, in this instance its finding the word discussing and selecting that "paragraph" (or lines that are grouped together between blank lines).

Comment: thanks, y'all. I think I got it. all I had to do was add the \n in the front and the back parts of the regex and it seems to only be pulling the two matches now.